# Gridview not populating while using a While() structure. C# ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sqldatareader

I am having problems with this grid view.  I am populating it with a query.  However, it will not populate or even appear if I use a while(reader.Read()) structure.  Without the while structure, it works fine.  However, I need to access two specific fields.  The code is below.

```
 SqlDataReader myReader;
 try
 {
     using (myConnection)
     {
         myConnection.Open();
         ArrayList arrliGames = new ArrayList();
         myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

         decimal decTicketCost = 0;
         int intTicketCount = 0;

         while (myReader.Read ())
         {
             decTicketCost = Convert .ToDecimal (myReader ["TicketCost"]);
             intTicketCount =Convert .ToInt32 (myReader ["NumTickets"]);
         }

         //Binds listbox
         grdEvents.DataSource = myReader ;
         grdEvents.DataBind();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Are you selecting more than 2 columns in your sql statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`SqlDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) is forward-only. When you first iterate over the rows, there is "nothing left" in it to display afterwards.

I suggest that you use the reader to populate a strongly-typed list in memory, and then bind the GridView to the list instead. Example:

```
var myList = new List<TicketInfo>();
while (myReader.Read())
{
    myList.Add(new TicketInfo
    {
        TicketCost = Convert.ToDecimal(myReader["TicketCost"]),
        NumTickets = Convert.ToInt32(myReader["NumTickets"])
    });
}
grdEvents.DataSource = myList;
grdEvents.DataBind();
```

The code example above assumes that you have a class called `TicketInfo` defined as:

```
class TicketInfo
{
    public decimal TicketCost { get; set; }
    public int NumTickets { get; set; }
}
```

If you haven't used generics (such as `List<TicketInfo>` in the example) before, I suggest you [do some reading on the subject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: @Nick remove your initial `while` block, the data reader will be enumerated when you call `DataBind`

Comment: I'm pretty new to c#.  What do you mean by strongly-typed list.  Could you show me an example of the process of which you are speaking?

Comment: @Nick Edited the post to include a simple example. By strongly-typed list, I really meant "generic list of appropriate type".

Comment: What allows me to use List<>?  My IDE keeps saying that it cannot be found

Comment: @Nick Add "[using System.Collections.Generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.aspx)" to the top of your file.

Comment: I just tried it and it no longer throws that error.  However, the grid still won't appear.  It won't appear even when I remove everything from the while().

Comment: @Nick ...and you have remembered to bind the GridView to the list, instead of the reader?

Comment: Hahaha.  I spaced that completely.  Thank you very much!  Problem solved!

Comment: How do I assign the values in TicketInfo to other vars.  I can't access the TicketInfo vars from outside of it, and I cannot access my page or Session vars from inside the class.  Also, how do I mark this as accepted?

Comment: There is a "checkbox outline" to the left of the answer which is used to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: As for the question regarding how to use the TicketInfo class etc, I suggest you post a new question that explains what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Should I post another question or edit this one?  Perhaps I should have been more clear.  I need the gridview to be populated by myReader, but I need two values from the table to be pulled as variables.  Your method puts them into a class, but by changing the datasource, my gridview now only returns the two which need to be stored in variables

Comment: Another question is better, since you have a new problem - before, you asked why the while-clause caused your GridView to be empty. I understand that your intent of the question might have been something else, but I think you will get more attention if you post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

create a class with two properties 
1. decTicketCost 
2. intTicketCount

now in while loop create instance and assign the value to the object properties

and add it in a list.

Finally bind the list.

Answer (score 1):

I guest you have set datasource to `myList` instead `myReader`

```
grdEvents.DataSource = myList;
```

**Edit:** You need to add other column in your list object.

```
while (myReader .Read ())
{
//myList-- Add other columns you need to display in the gridview
//As I don't know the your Data Reader column, I can't give you exact mylist object

 myList.Add(new TicketInfo{TicketCost = Convert.ToDecimal(myReader["TicketCost"]),NumTickets = Convert.ToInt32(myReader["NumTickets"])  });
}
```

Comment: If I do that, my gridview will only be populated by the ticket amount and ticket cost. As I said, I need the entire row to be present on the table.

Comment: I am very confused.  How will adding another column help?

Comment: in the very much same way, as you add 2 columns in your list.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace

```
while (myReader .Read ())                        
{                             
decTicketCost  = Convert .ToDecimal (myReader ["TicketCost"]);                            intTicketCount = Convert .ToInt32 (myReader ["NumTickets"]);                             
}                              
//Binds listbox                         
grdEvents.DataSource = myReader ;                         
grdEvents.DataBind();
```

to
    grdEvents.DataSource = myReader ;
    grdEvents.DataBind();

And then the gridview for some values

hope this help

Answer (score 0):

replace the following line

```
grdEvents.DataSource = myReader;
```

with

```
grdEvents.DataSource = myList;
```

Comment: If I do that, my gridview will only be populated by the ticket amount and ticket cost.  As I said, I need the entire row to be present on the table.

Comment: You should have the class having the required number of member variables to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
using (myConnection)
{
   myConnection.Open();
   DataSet ds = myCommand.ExecuteDataSet();

   //Binds listbox
   grdEvents.DataSource = ds;
   grdEvents.DataBind();                    
}
ForEach (DataRow dr in ds.tables[0].rows)
    myList.Add(new TicketInfo{TicketCost = Convert.ToDecimal(myReader["TicketCost"]),NumTickets = Convert.ToInt32(myReader["NumTickets"])  });
```

Comment: I suggested him to add the member variable to achieve it. If the variable declared in the class are not helping to accomplish it.