# How to populate a gridview while extracting individual column data in C# ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, data-binding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gridview not populating while using a While() structure. C# ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869953/gridview-not-populating-while-using-a-while-structure-c-asp-net)

I am attempting to pull the information about a sporting event from an SQL DB.  I am able to query the DB and get the information I need.  I need to have all the information for the GridView, as well as the COST and TICKETCOUNT column information for the row. (Note that it will only ever pull back one row at a time).  I can then assign it to a Gridview successfully.

However, I cannot seem to get the other two variables to assign.  If I try and do it during a while, it is no longer capable of populating the gridview.  I tried adding a generic class to get the information, but I cannot access the class data from outside the class, and I can't access external or Session variables from inside the class.  My code is below

```
public   int ticketCount = 0;
public      decimal decCost = 0;
class TicketInfo
    {
        public decimal TicketCost { get; set; }
        public int NumTickets { get; set; }
    }
```

That is my class.  Below is my Page_Load statement.  How can I get the two fields into external variables while still completely filling out my gridview?

```
SqlDataReader myReader;
        try
        {

            using (myConnection)
            {
                myConnection.Open();
                ArrayList arrliCost = new ArrayList();
                ArrayList arrliNum = new ArrayList();

                myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();


                var myList = new List<TicketInfo>();



               while (myReader .Read ())
               {
                 myList.Add(new TicketInfo{TicketCost = Convert.ToDecimal(myReader["TicketCost"]),NumTickets = Convert.ToInt32(myReader["NumTickets"])  });

               }

                //Binds listbox
                grdEvents.DataSource = myReader;
                grdEvents.DataBind();

            }

        }
```